# Is there a way to force an app to launch every time you restart or power up your iPhone using iOS 12?

Tags: iphone, ios12

I have a medical condition that requires an app to be running all the time.  It will only notify me of an issue if the app is running.  I am trying to figure out if there is a way to automatically launch a specific app on restart of the iOS and if there is a way to keep the app open if it was accidentally closed or check to see if an app is running.

Comment: No way to do this.

Comment: You should discuss with the producer of the app. This is generally possible if you integrate with external hardware, either by BLE or IAP2 (ExternalAccessory). But it's something the app would need to integrate. Even if you built a tool that integrated with your own hardware, you would need some kind of hook (such as a custom URL) to launch the other app, so you would still need to coordinate with the owner of the app. If you are the owner of the app, then we'll need more details about the specific constraints. The answer is "yes, if you control the app and hardware, otherwise no."

Comment: Note that there is no way to have "an app running all the time" in the broadest sense. Generally apps should not require this just to provide notifications. If this one does, then the app would need to be reworked. It's unclear whether you literally mean "always running" here or "capable of generating notifications." Again, more details are required in order to really answer this.

Comment: I am not the maker of the app.  The app needs to be open to allow it to communicate with an external Bluetooth device that is attached to my body. I will speak to the company to see if this could be a future upgrade.